# Number theory fermat's number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Why must $n$ be a power of two when $2^n + 1$ is prime and $n > 0$?

I understand that $2^n+1$ is prime only if $k$ is a power of $2$, butI don't understand why.

Can anyone explain this thoroughly?

Thank you. I need help.

Comment: In case $n$ has a nontrivial divisor $k$, try to factorize $2^n+1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $n=ab$ with $a$ odd, you can write $2^n+1=2^{ab}+1=(2^b)^a+1$, which is divisible by $2^b+1$ just like the sum of cubes. It follows that $n$ cannot have any odd factors, so must be a power of $2$. For a couple examples, $2^6+1=65$ is divisible by $2^2+1=5$ and $2^{15}+1=32769$ is divisible by both $9$ and $33$.

Comment: oops ... "power of $2$"